# STL vector of vectors - good idea? Mechanics of of resizing "inner" vector?

Tags: c++, data-structures, vector, stl

I frequently need to represent mappings from integers `0...N-1` to lists of some type `T`. To the individual lists I need to add elements dynamically to the end. `N` is usually known beforehand (but not at compile time). I need fast access to the individual lists.

I usually implement this using `vector<vector<T> > my_map(N)`, and I use `my_map[key].push_back(val)` to add elements.

I have two questions:

Is this an efficient and recommended way of realizing such a map?

Also, I wonder about contiguity of elements and its implications on resizing. Say, I add an element with `my_map[key].push_back(val)`, and `my_map[key]` with `key != N-1` needs to resize. Does this trigger a copy of the entire vector `my_map` in order to keep its contents contiguous? Or is `my_map` realized internally with pointers to vectors on the heap?

I am aware that this may depend on the STL implementation. I am primarily interested in the mechanics (and speed implications) with Visual Studio 2010, and GCC in Linux.

---

### Update

In the comments, @PeterWood pointed me towards `std::deque` as a container for the lists, which does not need re-allocation to grow. I did some unscientific benchmarking to compare `vector< deque<T> >` with `vector< vector<T> >` with `unsigned int` as `T`. For both, I timed 1 million lists with 30 elements, and 10,000 lists with 3000 elements each. Note that my tests reflect my typical application scenarios for this type of data structure.

I timed a random access "build-up", which works as follows:

```
vector<ContainerT> my_map(numKeys);
vector<unsigned int> random_keys(numKeys);
for (unsigned int i=0; i<numKeys; ++i) random_keys[i] = i;
random_shuffle(random_keys.begin(),random_keys.end());

for (auto pKey=random_keys.begin(); pKey!=random_keys.end(); ++pKey)
{
  for (unsigned int i=0; i<listSize; ++i)
  {
    my_map[*pKey].push_back( rand() );
  }
}
```

And I timed querying 30 million random elements from randomly chosen lists.

**Results**

`deque` is slightly faster in buildup for many small lists, but *way* slower in query than the vector for both scenarios. I conclude that I stay with `vector< vector<T> >` for my type of problems.

```
deque

Keys: 1000000, list size: 30
Mean time buildup: 1.29517 seconds
Mean time query: 4.17624 seconds

Keys: 10000, list size: 3000
Mean time buildup: 0.998761 seconds
Mean time query: 5.052 seconds


vector

Keys: 1000000, list size: 30
Mean time buildup: 1.5347 seconds
Mean time query: 1.63043 seconds

Keys: 10000, list size: 3000
Mean time buildup: 0.604954 seconds
Mean time query: 1.58328 seconds
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::map` of vectors? If your (integer) keys are not contiguous then that's probably a better solution.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I originally thought the same, however the OP states the size of the vectors is known at runtime. This means accessing each vector by an index is faster than through a map. From what I understand, after my_map has been initially populated, there is no need for it to resize at runtime, it won't change.

Comment: You should specify if you are using C++03 or C++11. C++11 will have near optimal behaviour due to move-constructors. C++03 might copy quite a bit.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: My integer keys are contiguous, and I really like the O(1) access to my individual lists.

Comment: @Zadirion: You understand correctly! The keys set is {0...N-1} and doesn't change.

Comment: @mirk: That's interesting. Could you elaborate on the difference the move constructors make here? Both C++ standards are relevant for my projects.

Comment: You probably want a `vector` of `deque`s.

Comment: @PeterWood: Is there an advantage of `deque` if I don't need to add elements to the front?

Comment: @DCS `deque` allows adding elements to the end without reallocation.

Comment: @PeterWood: Interesting, I will consider this! It seems I would only trade the O(1) back insertion of `vector` for an amortized O(n) back insertion in a `deque` acc. to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque. What still makes me skeptical is potential memory overhead, as the number of elements in `my_map` may be very large, and each individual list is quite small.

Comment: @DCS Sorry, I can't give an elaborate answer right now. I just wanted to mention move-constructors in C++11, since they are relevant for the discussion.

Comment: @DCS The docs you link say amortized `O(1)` not `O(n)`, same as [`vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @PeterWood: Sorry, typo. I will benchmark vector and dequqe.

Comment: @PeterWood: I added results of some simple benchmarking, concluding that I stay with `vector<vector<T> >`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this an efficient and recommended way of realizing such a map?

I think this is a perfectly reasonable way to implement such a map.

> Also, I wonder about contiguity of elements and its implications on resizing. Say, I add an element with `my_map[key].push_back(val)`, and `my_map[key]` with `key != N-1` needs to resize. Does this trigger a copy of the entire vector `my_map` in order to keep its contents contiguous? Or is `my_map` realized internally with pointers to vectors on the heap?

No, it does not trigger a copy of the entire outer vector. Only the sub-vectors are contiguous; the entire vector generally isn't.

As far as mental model goes, you can think of `my_map` as being an array of pointers to 1D arrays rather than a single contiguous 2D array.

Comment: If the final contained object class in the inner vector (row) is not move-able, does this not also mean the inner vector is also not movable, and therefore the outer vector will have not choice but to copy on a resize that exceeds capacity?

Comment: @WhozCraig: It probably does. However, only profiling can tell whether this is of any relevance.

Answer (score 0):

It copies the vector objects in the outer vector. But the objects on the heap inside those vectors are not reallocated.

Answer (score 0):

Each std::vector typically holds an internal pointer pointing to the memory where it allocates the array of objects of type T.

In a vector of vectors of such type T, resizing an inner vector would not resize the outer vector (`my_map` in your example), as the outer vector can be seen as only a vector of pointers to such arrays. The inner vector arrays are located in other memory locations than the outer vector.

For the same reason, there is no contiguity between the inner vectors of your `my_map`